# Pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm new to ANSI-C and I'm trying to figure out how this works:

```
bd_t *bd = gd->bd;
```

Is this telling me that `bd_t` = value of a structure value `bd`?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere, there is a typedef:

```
typedef something bd_t;
```

The line:

```
bd_t *bd = gd->bd;
```

declares a variable called `bd` as a pointer to a `bd_t`, and initializes it with the value of `gd->bd` from the pointer to structure variable `gd`.  That structure contains a member `bd` that is presumably also a `bd_t *`.

From the single line, you can't tell anything more about the type `bd_t`.